# Change color of nodes near coords based on value

Tags: pgfplots, color, nodes-near-coords

I have this matrix plot:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots, filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false]
\addplot [
matrix plot,
nodes near coords=\coordindex,mark=*,
mesh/cols=3,
point meta=explicit,
] table [meta=C] {
x y C
0 0 0
1 0 1
2 0 2
0 1 3
1 1 4
2 1 5
0 2 6
1 2 7
2 2 8
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to adapt the `nodes near coords` color based on the field color from the matrix plot, so that e.g. darker cells have white text?

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to change the color of the `nodes near coords`, you can make use of the option `coordinate style/.condition` like follows (it would leave the marks unaffected though):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false]
\addplot [
matrix plot,
nodes near coords=\coordindex,
mark=*,
mesh/cols=3,
point meta=explicit,
coordinate style/.condition={meta < 1 || meta > 7}{
    white,
},
] table [meta=C] {
x y C
0 0 0
1 0 1
2 0 2
0 1 3
1 1 4
2 1 5
0 2 6
1 2 7
2 2 8
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jasper, thank you for your answer! That's exactly what I was looking for!